# affdex-sdk build failed - compile error

Tags: affdex-sdk

Ld /Users/xxxxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Affectiva-cwgdzearaapwhxcpqywcfkycewwz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Affectiva.app/Affectiva normal x86_64
    cd /Users/xxxxxxx/Desktop/Affectiva
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=9.3
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.3.sdk -L/Users/xxxxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Affectiva-cwgdzearaapwhxcpqywcfkycewwz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/xxxxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Affectiva-cwgdzearaapwhxcpqywcfkycewwz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/xxxxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Affectiva-cwgdzearaapwhxcpqywcfkycewwz/Build/Intermediates/Affectiva.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Affectiva.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Affectiva.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -mios-simulator-version-min=9.3 -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -framework Affdex -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/xxxxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Affectiva-cwgdzearaapwhxcpqywcfkycewwz/Build/Intermediates/Affectiva.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Affectiva.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Affectiva_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/xxxxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Affectiva-cwgdzearaapwhxcpqywcfkycewwz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Affectiva.app/Affectiva

ld: framework not found Affdex
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

---

N00b question.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This error:

```
ld: framework not found Affdex clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

indicates that the linker cannot find Affdex.framework.

Did you drag the Affdex.framework file into your Xcode project? This action allows Xcode to associate the framework with your project and the linker error should be resolved.

Note that you will also need to add Affdex.framework as an embedded binary so that it is copied into your app at build time. This can be done by selecting the target app in Xcode, then going to the "General" tab and adding Affdex.framework to the "Embedded Binaries" section.